# Create Georeference in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I work with R to analyse satellite data from MODIS (file attached). I want to georeference my `.image/.tif` file using R. This is my script that I used:

```
library(raster)

x <- raster('bali_test.tif')
extent(x) <- c(114,115,-8,-7)
projection(x) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS![enter image description here][1]84")
```

Unfortunately, when I plot it using `levelplot` and world map, it appears in the wrong position. The white area is land/island, and the black line is the Indonesian coastline

Comment: R is not the right tool for georeferencing. And this kind of question should be asked in http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Pascal Why R is not the right tool? It has a lot of packages that handle georeferencing. See for instance `rgdal` and `rgeos`. Don't know if they migth answer the question, since it is not reproducible, but I guess they could.

Comment: @nicola Regarding the question, the OP wants to georeference an image, i.e. to create geographical reference. And R is not the best tool for this task. If it is not what the OP is meaning, then the question has to be modified.

Comment: @Pascal I guess he wants to plot the image on a world map. If he knows the reference system, the projection and the extent of the image, he can inverse project the points of the image to geographical coordinates and then convert them back to an existing plot.

Comment: @nicola It is not my understanding of both the title ("Create") and the question.

Comment: @Pascal I agree with nicola. I use geospatial tools and modelling packages in R extensively. And what the OP is *trying* to do is perfectly achievable in R, with packages designed for that purpose. Unfortunately, without more information about the shapefile used for plotting or more information on the `.tif` file it is hard to say (most likely the projection of the world map is different to the raster).

Comment: I just say R is not the best tool for georeferencing.

Comment: @Pascal so that is where you and I have a difference of opinion! :-) I prefer it over such atrocities as <shudder> ArcGIS.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon I don't use such commercial software ;-). Anyway, R is very good at working with georeferenced data. To me, it failed to easy create georeferencement.

Comment: You question say "file attached", but it isn't. Where is the file?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the levelplot() function from the rasterVis package. The levelplot function you are using is not for raster matrix.